# Identification of this Salamander

Tags: zoology, species-identification, herpetology

This salamander was found in a small forest pond somewhat near the Oregon coast. In the area are many rough skinned newts and a small number of another type of salamander that I still can't find the species of. I'm guessing it is either the salamander species or a rough skinned newt.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I found what it is, it's a torrent salamander.

Answer (score 3):

It is a [torrent salamander](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torrent_salamander). Most likely this is the southern torrent salamander (*Rhyacotriton variegatus*)

Comment: I'm not convinced this is a Torrent salamander (Rhyacotriton variegatus)... I'll look into this a bit...